# Triggering a script using an email

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation, user-management

I have a mail server configured on my server (Postfix), I have a script which requires input to be provided to it.

I would like to know if there is a possibility to trigger this script by sending mail to the server.

This is what I am thinking:

Once the mail arrives on server, the mail will contain all the input that script needs.

The script will use these variables in it and complete the script.

Example. The script needs following input:

```
1 : Username
2 : uid
3 : email address
4 : Group name
```

Is there a possibility to make the script run once a mail comes in and then use the inputs from the mail to finish the job?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/132576/run-script-on-incoming-email-message-to-postfix

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/132576/run-script-on-incoming-email-message-to-postfix

While this is interesting, I am still a script kiddie to understand this, if someone can help me a bit more, I would really appreciate it